# Chromium-Chromedriver missing library libgfx on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run Chromium in headless mode on Raspberry Pi 3. I got Chromium-chromedriver from [this repository](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/chromium-chromedriver). I keep getting the same error. When I try running chromium-chromedriver from terminal it says I am missing libgfx.so, which after intensely looking for I can't find anywhere for Raspberry Pi. I aslo tried installing from the terminal. Below is my code along with everything I have tried and the correspodning errors. Any and all help is appreciated at this point.

**My code:**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from contextlib import closing
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)) as driver:
    driver.get(URL)
```

**Gives the error:**

```
python3 Chromium\ Launch\ Test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Chromium Launch Test.py", line 3, in <module>

with closing(Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)) as driver:

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__

self.service.start()

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start

self.assert_process_still_running()

File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running

% (self.path, return_code)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 12
```

**Trying to run chromium-chromedriver from terminal:**

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgfx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Trying to install libgfx from terminal:**

```
sudo apt install libgfx

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package libgfx
```

Literally no clue where to go. Tried updating before launching. Tried updating all dependent libraries listed in the repository individually. Nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been fighting this exact same issue.   After setting up an ubuntu vm and completing my dev there so I knew solution worked I wanted to move it back to my pi.  I found this driver and it works https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.6.0/chromedriver-v2.21-linux-armv7l.zip

Comment: YOU SIR. You are a legend. It appears you created an account just to answer my question. I honestly can't express how thankful I am. I have spent a week on this problem. It threatened to tank my ENTIRE PROJECT of one year in the making. You saved me. Thank you so much. Really. Hero.

Comment: This saved me! Thank you!